# Get content generate by ASPX using node.js

Tags: asp.net, node.js, cheerio

I'm going to fetch some data from a ASPX site and since the data's value change time by time it was generate by ASPX script.

When I use cheerio code and tried to fetch the value I found out an issue, a API GET request can only get ASPX source (looks like the script that generate the data) but can't get the current data that's showing (the data you can view in browser).

When I found the above issue I tried to solve it but I can't, I tried to search something like `get aspx content by node.js` but can't find any useful result.

So, how can I get the ASPX script generated value (the value that normal browser visitor can see) using node.js

Comment: Assuming the server is configured correctly, you should never see the original source for an ASPX page on a client machine. You should only see the rendered HTML. What does the source look like you're receiving? What does your own code look like?

Comment: It's a Chinesse website [here](https://taqm.epa.gov.tw/taqm/aqi-map.aspx) and I get something like [this](view-source:https://taqm.epa.gov.tw/taqm/aqi-map.aspx)

Comment: If they load content after the initial request, you'll either need to manually retrieve that content by hitting the same endpoints or use a tool that can execute JavaScript (such as Selenium) to load the page.

Comment: Can you tell how they generate it? I want the value next to AQI in the website

Comment: @mason then how do you run the js script inside the node.js like creating a sandbox or so?